# Chain, V pulley, Timing Belt

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

I'm trying to create a mechanical setup to transfer motion from a motor to two shafts. I need a method to do it that fits the following criteria to the greatest extent possible:

1. Does not slip
2. Does not introduce vibration

It's not a strenuous job with a lot of torque behind it. None the less I did quite like the idea of the chain or timing belt.

My question is twofold

A) Would a chain or timing belt introduce extra vibration to the system compared with a v belt?

B) Is there a way to get V belts slip free?

Comment: What about toothed belts as commonly used for cars? Slip free...

Comment: @SolarMike That's what I meant by toothed belt - sorry. But would that introduce vibration?

Comment: You mean that's what you meant by "timing belt"? But all methods may induce some level of vibration, even gears... You have to decide what level you will accept and what you can deal with.

Comment: @SolarMike That doesn't really answer the question though - does one method introduce more vibration than another?

Comment: Well, are you after zero vibration? what about building vibration - come up with some parameters then the different methods can be examined. PS comments don't have to answer a question, they can be, and are, used to elicit clarity...

Comment: @SolarMike I appreciate your comments but still looking for an answer to the questions asked. Would a chain or timing belt introduce extra vibration to the system compared with a v belt? I'm asking this because when the chain meshes with the sproket I could foresee this being a cause of vibration but some might disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Vibration is everywhere.

There is a principal frequency and its harmonics.

Since most of the energy is in the principal frequency we concern ourselves with that.

Say we call the distance between the two pullies L.

$ L = \lambda /2  $

The energy of vibration is inversely related to the tension in the belt.

You have to judge which belt lend itself to your setting better.

The chain belts are heavy and call for more substantial pullies and tension free wheels.

Rubber indented belts are versatile and won't slip either.

You can google for standing vawes on cords and belts and gather detailed information.